# Gmail API Loading Taking more time with 50 threads - ASP .Net WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am creating w web application with ASP .Net WEB API for integrating GMail API.
I am reading threads then reading messages on each thread id with a loop of threads.
It is taking too much loading to get response. Please help me if i did anything wrong.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: ListRequest req = gs.Users.Threads.List(me);
req.LabelIds = "INBOX";
req.MaxResults = 50;
res threadResponse = req.Execute();
foreach (Thread eachThread in res.Threads)
{
    GetRequest req = gs.Users.Threads.Get(EmailAddress, eachThread.Id);
    req.Format = ThreadsResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;
    req.Fields = "id, messages(id,labelIds/*,payload/headers(name,value))";
    Thread thcon = req.Execute();
    Message lmsg = thcon.Messages.LastOrDefault();
    EmailList.Add(lmsg);
}

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

you need to remember this is a free api you are limited by what google will allow.

you could try batching but its only going to help up until the point where you get throttled for going to fast.

I don't think you are doing anything wrong